# create and bind widget button dynamically in python

Tags: python, button, widget, kivy

Hey guys I asked this question on kivy but could not get an answer. Maybe someone could help on this forum. I have a project that is to read a file line for line, store certain data elements in a list, make buttons for them then make them separately perform another action once clicked. I made an example of it but a list has been prepared. I want to create a app that will create widgets then bind them individually without me having to manually type out the binding method. All of this is to be done dynamically, no matter how many entries the list holds.

```
inventory = [ 'Honda', 'Lincoln', 'Ford', 'Toyota']

Class Vehicle(GridLayout):    
    def __init__(self, **kwarg):    
        super(Vehicle, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        rws = 1    
        for li in inventory  
           btn = Button(text = str(li))    
           btn.bind(on_release=clk)   
           self.rows = rows
           self.add_widget(btn)


def click(self, object)
   print(?)

class My_app(self):    
    def build (self):    
        return Vehical()

My_app().run()
```

My goal is to make each button clickable with the ability to print the name of each button...such as button(Toyota) click- Print "Toyota". I really am lost on how to make this happen. I am still fairly new to python and kivy. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Forgive me if I not using the correct terminology.
Thanks

Comment: you should probably bind it to `self.clk` not just `clk` ... and then in clk `print ob.text`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks... the simple correction made it work perfectly.!!